# Mas de dos variables en .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Es la primera vez que tengo que trabajar con .htacces para hacer URL amigables. Con el siguiente código he podido hacer que esta URL http://localhost/trafico/index.php?c=tarea se convierta a http://localhost/trafico/tarea

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Pero,  actualmente no he podido hacer que funcione para una segunda y tercera variable.  Por ejemplo con esta URL http://localhost/trafico/index.php?c=tarea&a=Crud&id=21.  ¿Como se puede hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es sencillo, siguiendo el mismo ejemplo que ya estabas usando, con un patrón por variable (ajusta presencia de minúsculas, mayúculas y números según tus necesidades). Por ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Si puede darse el caso de que tengas 1, 2 o 3 variables en tus urls, debes especificar todos los casos. Sería algo así:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1&a=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Correspondería a:

http://localhost/trafico/tarea/subtarea/caso

http://localhost/trafico/tarea/subtarea

http://localhost/trafico/tarea

Comment: Como deberia de colocar los links o hipervinculos?  Por ejemplo como deberia de colocar la siguiente linea para que funcionara bien <a href="?c=tarea&a=Crud&id='.$id.'">

Comment: Si siempre vas a tener las 3 variables si, si puedes tener 1, 2 o 3 tienes que especificar todos los casos, de más varibles a menos. Edito la respuesta para aclarlo.

Comment: Otra pregunta.  Me estan funcionando bien las url amigable,  pero los estilos css no aparecen.  Hay debo de enrutar nuevamente los estilos?

Comment: Para el css se comporta como si cada slash "/" fuera un carpeta. Si lo estas añadiendo con una ruta relativa tienes que reescribirla de acuerdo a la url o bien cargarlo con una ruta absoluta.